# Implementing mousePressEvent and setDragMode in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am doing a project in which I should implement mousePressEvent and setDragMode on QGraphicsScene. I am able to implement individually but I should implement both at the same time. I included both into the code but only mousePressEvent is  working and not able to drag the scene . Could you please anyone tell me that how to implement both.Please find the attached code. Thankyou.

**MyGraphicsView.cpp**

```
 MyGraphicsView::MyGraphicsView(QWidget* parent) : QGraphicsView(parent) {

    Scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    setScene(Scene);

    setDragMode(ScrollHandDrag);
}

void MyGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *eve)
{ 
    if (eve->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
    // handle Left mouse button here
    QPointF pt = mapToScene(eve->pos());
    }
}
```

**MyGraphicsView.h**

```
 class MyGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{  
  Q_OBJECT   

    protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *eve);
}
```

Comment: Surely you should call the base class  implementation of `mousePressEvent(..)` in your implementation, as your implementation does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

From QGraphicsView Qt docs on DragMode property:

> (...) The default value, NoDrag, does nothing.
>
> This behavior only affects mouse clicks that are not handled by any item. You can define a custom behavior by creating a subclass of QGraphicsView and reimplementing mouseMoveEvent().

This is probably why you can't make a DragMode to get to work when you implement a **mousePressEvent**: The event is processed, so the Qt framework thinks the "job is done", and no need to trigger a drag.

The doc suggest to re-implement the **mouseMoveEvent**. It still provides a **QMouseEvent**, so you can get the coordinates, and the information that what mouse button is currently pressed. From that on you only have to implement a state machine for *Idle; StartDrag; Drag; FinishDrag*

according to what buttons are pressed during a move, and implement your desired functionality in whichever states you need them.

Comment: the problem has been solved after implementing the base class thank you @FPGA warrior